# Entry and Picker not supported in a Windows Universal project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've created a Xamarin.Forms solution (latest version of Xamarin and VS 2017 CE) and I have projects targetting Android, iOS and UWP.

I've created a user control in the shared project and I've tried to add an Entry and a Picker control to it but I get a compile error that says "Entry is not supported in a Windows Universal project." and "Picker is not supported in a Windows Universal project.".  I can find no indication in any of the documentation that these controls are incompatible with UWP and I've found examples where people appear to be using these controls quite happily in UWP projects.

Am I missing something?  If it is not possible to use these controls then what is the point of Xamarin.Forms?  I thought it was meant to prevent having to create entirely different UIs for each platform.

Also my user control is in the namespace MyApp.Views and the xaml has the line "xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Views"" automatically generated.  This also generates a compile error: "Undefined namespace.  The 'using' URI refers to a namespace 'MyApp.Views' that could not be found.".  This is auto-generated and the code behind is clearly in that namespace so I'm unclear what this is about either.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.Views.SomeControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="64"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Picker x:Name="demographics" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Picker>
        <Entry x:Name="filter" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"></Entry>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Is this an error in the IDE, a compile error, or a runtime error?  Is your user control in the shared project?

Comment: It's a compile error.  User control is in the shared project.

Comment: please post the relevant code and the specific error message

Comment: I posted the exact error message in my post.  The xaml is just basic <Entry></Entry> etc.

Comment: You are trying to mix XF XAML with a UWP UserControl.  That’s not how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the Xamarin Forms version of a UWP UserControl is ContentView.

Create the Xamarin Forms control in the "MyApp" project, not the "MyApp.UWP" project; example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.MyContentView">
  <ContentView.Content>
    <Entry />
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Usage, e.g. in `MainPage.xaml` in the "MyApp" project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
         x:Class="MyApp.MainPage">
  <local:MyContentView/>
</ContentPage>
```